# Automorphism of a Field Completely Determined by How it Maps Generators

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, field-theory

**Question**:

Show that if the field $K$ is generated over $F$ by the elements $\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_n$ then an automorphism $\sigma$ of $K$ fixing $F$ is uniquely determined by $\sigma(\alpha_1), ..., \sigma(\alpha_n)$.  In particular show that an automorphism fixes $K$ if and only if it fixes a set of generators for $K$.

**My attempt**:

Let $\sigma \in \text{Aut}(K/F)$ and let $x \in K$.  Since $K$ is generated over $F$
by the elements $\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_n$ we have $K = F(\alpha_1, ..., 
\alpha_n)$.  Since one or more of the elements $\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_n$ may be transcendental over $F$ an arbitrary element $x$ in $K$ can be expressed as

$$
x = \frac{f(\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_n)}{g(\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_n)},
$$

where $f(X_1, ..., X_n), g(X_1, ..., X_n) \in F[X_1, ..., X_n]$ and $g(\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_n) \neq 0$.  These are multivariable polynomials, so

$$
f(\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_n) = c_1\alpha_1^{\beta_{1,1}}...\alpha_n^{\beta_{1,n}} + ... + c_k\alpha_1^{\beta_{k,1}}...\alpha_n^{\beta_{k,n}}
$$

and

$$
g(\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_n) = d_1\alpha_1^{\partial_{1,1}}...\alpha_n^{\partial_{1,n}} + ... + d_j\alpha_1^{\partial_{j,1}}...\alpha_n^{\partial_{j,n}}
$$

for some natural numbers $j$ and $k$, coefficients $c_1, ..., c_k, d_1, ..., d_j \in F$.  Then

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{split}
    \sigma(x) &= \sigma\bigg(\frac{f(\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_n)}{g(\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_n)} \bigg)    \\[8pt]
    &= \sigma \bigg( \frac{c_1\alpha_1^{\beta_{1,1}}...\alpha_n^{\beta_{1,n}} + ... + c_k\alpha_1^{\beta_{k,1}}...\alpha_n^{\beta_{k,n}}}{d_1\alpha_1^{\partial_{1,1}}...\alpha_n^{\partial_{1,n}} + ... + d_j\alpha_1^{\partial_{j,1}}...\alpha_n^{\partial_{j,n}}} \bigg) \\[8pt]
    &= \sigma(c_1\alpha_1^{\beta_{1,1}}...\alpha_n^{\beta_{1,n}} + ... + c_k\alpha_1^{\beta_{k,1}}...\alpha_n^{\beta_{k,n}})\Big(\sigma(d_1\alpha_1^{\partial_{1,1}}...\alpha_n^{\partial_{1,n}} + ... + d_j\alpha_1^{\partial_{j,1}}...\alpha_n^{\partial_{j,n}}\Big)^{-1} \\[8pt]
    &= \frac{c_1\sigma(\alpha_1^{\beta_{1,1}})...\sigma(\alpha_n^{\beta_{1,n}}) + ... + c_k\sigma(\alpha_1^{\beta_{k,1}})...\sigma(\alpha_n^{\beta_{k,n}})}{d_1\sigma(\alpha_1^{\partial_{1,1}})...\sigma(\alpha_n^{\partial_{1,n}}) + ... + d_j\sigma(\alpha_1^{\partial_{j,1}})...\sigma(\alpha_n^{\partial_{j,n}})} \\[8pt]
    &= \frac{c_1\sigma(\alpha_1)^{\beta_{1,1}}...\sigma(\alpha_n)^{\beta_{1,n}} + ... + c_k\sigma(\alpha_1)^{\beta_{k,1}}...\sigma(\alpha_n)^{\beta_{k,n}}}{d_1\sigma(\alpha_1)^{\partial_{1,1}}...\sigma(\alpha_n)^{\partial_{1,n}} + ... + d_j\sigma(\alpha_1)^{\partial_{j,1}}...\sigma(\alpha_n)^{\partial_{j,n}}} \\[8pt]
    \end{split}
\end{equation*}

Hence, $\sigma(x)$ is completely determined by $\sigma(b_1), ..., \sigma(b_m)$.  The choice of $x \in K$ is arbitrary though, and since $b_1, ..., b_m$ are elements of the generating set $(\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_n)$ it follows that $\sigma$ is completely determined by $\sigma(\alpha_1), ..., \sigma(\alpha_n)$ as claimed.

Now, suppose that an automorphism $\tau$ fixes $K$.  Then $\tau:K \rightarrow K$ is the identity isomorphism for all elements of $K$, including the set of generators of $K$ (which are of course contained in $K$), so $\tau$ fixes the set of generators $\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_n$.  Conversely if $\tau$ fixes all of $\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_n$ then for $x \in K$ an arbitrary element as above we have that

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{split}
        \tau(x) &= \frac{c_1\tau(\alpha_1)^{\beta_{1,1}}...\tau(\alpha_n)^{\beta_{1,n}} + ... + c_k\tau(\alpha_1)^{\beta_{k,1}}...\tau(\alpha_n)^{\beta_{k,n}}}{d_1\tau(\alpha_1)^{\partial_{1,1}}...\tau(\alpha_n)^{\partial_{1,n}} + ... + d_j\tau(\alpha_1)^{\partial_{j,1}}...\tau(\alpha_n)^{\partial_{j,n}}} \\[8pt]
        &= \frac{c_1\alpha_1^{\beta_{1,1}}...\alpha_n^{\beta_{1,n}} + ... + c_k\alpha_1^{\beta_{k,1}}...\alpha_n^{\beta_{k,n}}}{d_1\alpha_1^{\partial_{1,1}}...\alpha_n^{\partial_{1,n}} + ... + d_j\alpha_1^{\partial_{j,1}}...\alpha_n^{\partial_{j,n}}} \\[8pt]
        &= x
    \end{split}
\end{equation*}

with the assumption that $\tau$ is an automorphism which fixes $F$.  So indeed $\tau$ is the identity automorphism on $K$.

Edit: After looking through some other posts I believe that I need to consider the possibility that the generators may not be algebraic over the base field $F$.  Without this assumption, I believe the proof above works but I'm not sure if I have the details correct.